# USB3 port doesn't work on kernel 4.10

Tags: usb, kernel, asus

When kernel of my Ubuntu 16.04.2 upgraded to version 4.10, USB3 port doesn't work.

How can I solve this problem? Is it a good idea to upgrade the kernel to upper version?

I had this problem by kernel 4.10 when I had Ubuntu 17.04. My laptop is Asus k46-cb

Comment: It's probably a bug, and I am not sure you can solve it all by yourself. File a bug report.

Comment: @ahmad as per kernel bug reporting, you need to test mainline kernel https://askubuntu.com/q/119080/26246 if still have same issue. Reference: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Bugs